# Remove specific a tags from html

Tags: php, html-parsing

i m parsing various html pages on my website. there are some specific 'a' tags i wish to remove.
all a tags look like this:

```
<a href="#cite-note-2"><span>..</span></a>
<a href="#cite-sub">....</a>
```

so what i want is to remove all a tags in which href starts with #cite

please suggest some regEx in php. thanks

Comment: no. using regexes on HTML, especialy for manipulation, is a BAD idea. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead.

Comment: Regex ar often fine for extracting (not 'parsing') from text intersparsed with angle brackets. They are unsuitable for newcomers however. And if you don't know regex you shouldn't attempt it. Moreover don't ask the internet for providing magic black box codes to do so. -- Simpler solutions are phpQuery or QueryPath; but yes, still require some research on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex:

`'/<a[\s]{1,}href=[\'"]\#cite.*?[\'"].*?>.*?<\/a>/ims'`

.

for example:

`$a = preg_replace('/<a[\s]{1,}href=[\'"]\#cite.*?[\'"].*?>.*?<\/a>/ims', '', $a);`

Comment: thanks a ton. also, can u link me to a reliable page where i can learn how to build custom RegEx ??

Comment: hmm. I got a couple of documents you might be interested in instead. email me at my temporary email address rh2@yopmail.com. I will reply back the document.